# Trying to play audio with Swift AVPlayer

Tags: ios, swift, audio, avplayer

Here's my current ViewController:

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class SecondViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        var player = AVPlayer()
            let url = "http://www.nasa.gov/mp3/640149main_Computers%20are%20in%20Control.mp3"
            let playerItem = AVPlayerItem( URL:NSURL( string:url ) )
            player = AVPlayer(playerItem:playerItem)
            player.rate = 1.0;
            player.play()
    }
}
```

When I run this in the simulator I get no audio, could it be that the iOS sim doesn't play audio, or an issue with my code?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Move the line:

```
    var player = AVPlayer()
```

... so that it is *before* the line:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
```

Comment: Good! :) So if you have nothing at all to do, you can read about it here: http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch03.html#_variable_scope_and_lifetime You had a _local_ variable, so it died instantly before it could even play. I moved it up a level to be an _instance_ variable so it persists as long as the view controller persists.

Comment: Thanks for the link, will read up on it. Could you clarify what you mean by 'it died instantly before it could even play'?

Comment: After the line `player.play()` the `viewDidLoad` method comes to an end. Therefore all local variables declared inside it die. That is what a local variable is. It dies when execution passes out of its scope.

Comment: Right, and wouldn't that make sense? It finally hits `player.play()` which plays the audio file and that's it.

Comment: But the code doesn't stop. It doesn't _wait_ while the player plays. It goes right on instantly and the method ends and the player dies. Meanwhile, playing takes _time_. If the player dies how can it play? It needs to live long enough to play.